# How to replace a Docker data volume with another at runtime?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to replace a Docker data volume with another one at runtime without interrupting other containers that access data inside the data volume.

Is there presently any way to do this with Docker?

If not, what is a container strategy where I can have a separate data container that will be accessed by other containers/services but where I can swap out the data container without causing service interruptions at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without tweaking the container at runtime . You can have a look at the approach suggested [here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/01/13/docker-mount-dynamic-volumes/)

Depending on the type of the data, there are other alternatives.

On my side, I had a similar requirement where some website static resources where managed outside the application in a data container. My resources where "packaged" in a container, but swapping this data container to move from one version to another at runtime didn't work.

I moved to a different strategy where I have a generic side-car container which pull the code from a separate git repo on demand. Hence I can easily upgrade the version of my data container without restarting anything.